# Can anyone to add progaurd rules for my project

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is project app level gradle...Kinldy give rules based on these dependices.My exact problem is crashing application when retrofit request hit.I am using Kotlin and androidX.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Material Components for Android
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'


    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

    //LifeCycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'


    //Facebook AccountKit

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:5.+'

    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    -keep class com.facebook.stetho.** { *; }         +
    -dontwarn com.facebook.stetho.**                  +

    -dontwarn okhttp3.**                                
    -dontwarn okio.**
    -dontwarn javax.annotation.**
    -dontwarn org.conscrypt.**                        +
```

This will probably be more than enough. You can experiment with the lines I marked + and remove them to see if it still works.

In future you can do this yourself. While building your project there will be an error indicating which class couldn't be found so you can just keep the classes that your code requires but proguard eliminates